# Img responsive inside div with fix height width (full width slider)

Tags: html, css, slide

I'm trying to create a slider as a fullwidth header, when I set fixed width & height, my img are not responsive, it is cutoff if I pull the `browswer width`. 
then I set `width:100%`, `height:auto` then the whole img is resized.

I want the img responsive inside of that `fullwidth` div like this site http://www.jssor.com/demos/full-width-slider.slider, please help me if there are any tutorial(s).

```
  <div id="home_slider">
    <div class="flexslider">
      <ul class="slides">
          <li><div style="background-image:url('/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/ABC1.jpg');"></div></li>
          <li><div style="background-image:url('/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/ABC2.jpg');"></div></li>
          <li><div style="background-image:url('/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/ABC3.jpg');"></div></li>
          <li><div style="background-image:url('/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/ABC4.jpg');"></div></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>



  .flexslider ul.slides li >div {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: 100% center;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should use image in `<img>` rather than in background. and give width:100%;

Comment: This should be added in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, put the images in `<img>` tags.
You can then give those images the properties:
`height: 100%; width; 100%; object-fit: cover;`

This should make it so that your image resizes to fit, rather than stretching.

Answer (score 0):

You can export he code what it says on the website and edit it.

Comment: This should be added in the comments.

Comment: I can't i do not have enough reputation